# Javascript new RegExp vs. /pattern/ and multi line

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is the /pattern/ matching, but the RegExp not?

```
<div id="foo">
##content##
<h1>works!</h1>
##/content##
</div>

<script>
var str = document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML;
console.log(str);

var r = new RegExp("##content##([\S\s]*)##\/content##", "img");

console.log(r.exec(str)); //null
console.log(str.match(/##content##([\S\s]*)##\/content##/img)); //matches
</script>
```

Comment: Not the answer but you're missing the `?` in the second regex and the first one doesn't require escaping the `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
var r = new RegExp("##content##([\S\s]*?)##\/content##", "img");
```

It should be replaced with:

```
var r = new RegExp("##content##([\\S\\s]*?)##\/content##", "img");
```

**Reason:** Understand that RegExp object takes a String as argument to construct and you need to double escape `\S` and `\s` to be correctly interpreted by RegEx engine so `\S` should become `\\S` and \s should become `\\s` in your regex.

Comment: Just to add. Inside of a string, `\S` is an invalid escape sequence which is interpreted as `S`. So you have to escape the escape character to use it literally (hence the double escaping).